# when i download file from my website which contains grid and in one of the column of grid there is download button

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, iis-6

I have page called filedownload.aspx , it contains grid and in grid they are three columns and in one of the column there is button which says Download , when user clicks on that button it picks file id and gives the download box to user with three options 
Open save and cancel .

Now the problem is that when user clicks on the download button in grid it gives this ERROR:
INTERNET EXPLORER CANNOT DOWNLOAD FILEDOWNLOAD.ASPX FROM ABC.XYZ.COM (MY URL EXAMPLE)
INTERNET EXPLORER WAS NOT ABLE TO OPEN THIS SITE .THE REQUEST SITE IS EITHER UNAVAILABLE OR CANNOT BE FOUND .

ONE MORE THING IS THT RECENTLY WE IMPLEMENTED SSL AND FROM HTTP WE MOVE TO HTTPS WITH NAME CHANGE IN URL ALSO BFEORE IT WAS  AND NOW ITS  .

NOW WHEN I CHANGE THE URL TO OLD ONE THE PAGE IS WORKING FINE .

CAN ANYONE HELP ME ON THIS ?

My code :my code:

protected void gdvfiledownload_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
               if (e.CommandName == "Download")
               {
                 int indexfile = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                 GridViewRow row = gdvfiledownload.Rows[indexfile];
                 string fileuserid = Ldapinfo.getName(Page.User.Identity.Name);
                 string batchfilename = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Text.ToString());
                 //string requestedby = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Text.ToString());

```
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString.ToString());
            cn.Open();
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring "].ConnectionString.ToString());
            con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_Insert_CAV2_File", cn);
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_proc ", cn);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch_name", batchfilename);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@curr_user", fileuserid);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            da.Fill(ds);
            StringBuilder  strFD = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    strFD.Append(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());
                    strFD.Append(" ");
                }
                strFD.AppendLine();
            }

            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Notepad.txt");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.text";
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

            Response.Write(strFD.ToString());
            Response.End();
            cn.Close();
            con.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblfilemess.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

THANKS,
SMARTDEV

Answer (score 0):

With a little research I found a couple possible causes:

1) This problem can occur if the "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" check box is selected in Internet Explorer if you're using IE 6.0 SP1.

2) The cause could also be a known IIS 6 issue with caching.  Try these steps and see if they solve the problem:

- Open IIS Admin
- View the properties for the website
- Click the HTTP Headers Tab
- Uncheck the Enable Content Expiration checkbox.

Sources:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812935
http://www.alagad.com/blog/post.cfm/error-internet-explorer-cannot-download-filename-from-webserver